# Swift Compiler Error on Pods

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I made single view application and install pods. I'm using Alamofire, SwifttyJSON,HanekeSwift, and RealmSwift. after the installation, i open .xcworkspace and then get so many errors like this

[image]

I trying Reinstalling Pods and also removing SwiftyJSON but another errors comes up. And my group Pods looks like this

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: deintegrate pods from your project and install again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are using a lower version of Xcode and swift is lower while current alamofire and swiftyjson are updated to support xcode 8+ and swift 3.0 or above. You will need to use specific pod to use it in lower xcode.

To go to specific version of pod you need to do it like this

pod 'Alamofire', '3.1.2'

else if you use like 'Alamofire' or 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.2', it will take latest version in the first case and in second latest minimum version 3.1.2, so you will not get the exact version you want try the above i mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Open terminal.
2. `cd` to your project directory.
3. Run `rm -rf Pods`.
4. Run `pod install`.

If the above does not work please paste your Podfile so I can assist you further.

Comment: still doesn't work. I use `pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.2’
  pod 'HanekeSwift', '~> 0.10'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.98'` and my XCode version is 7.0.1

Comment: @ArielGemilang You are doing it wrong check my answer i have edited

Comment: Just seen this, Parth's answer is indeed correct and should solve your problem; though I recommend you think about updating to Xcode 7.3.1 instead.

Comment: It solved my problem. googleapi agent was not found in my case even i updated pod. so completely removed with above command and installed.